# Ethereum Transaction Error while calling a contract function from another contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, geth, kaleido

Following smart contract works fine in Remix and Ganache. However doesn't work on private ethereum blockchains like Kaleido or Azure. What am I missing. When I call setA it consumes all gas and then fails.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract TestA {
    uint public someValue;

    function setValue(uint a) public returns (bool){
        someValue = a;
        return true;
    }
}

contract TestB {
    address public recentA;

    function createA() public returns (address) {
        recentA = new TestA();
        return recentA;
    }

    function setA() public returns (bool) {
        TestA(recentA).setValue(6);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hitting the limit of gas allowed to be spent per block. Information about gas limit is included into every block, so you can check what's this value is right now in your blockchain. Currently on Ethereum MainNet, GasLimit (per block) is about 8 millions (see here https://etherscan.io/blocks)

To fix this, you can start your blockchain with modified genesis file. Try to increase value of `gasLimit` parameter in your genesis file, which specifies the maximum amount of gas processed per block.  Try `"gasLimit": "8000000"`.

Comment: I have modified the genesis file and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I tried your contract in Kaleido, and found even calling eth_estimateGas with very large numbers was resulting in "out of gas".

I changed the `setValue` cross-contract call to set a gas value, and I was then able to call setA, and estimating the gas for `setA` showed just 31663.

`recentA.setValue.gas(10000)(6);`

I suspect this EVM behavior is related to permissioned chains with a gasprice of zero. However, that is speculation as I haven't investigated the internals.

I've also added eth_estimateGas, and support for multiple contracts in a Solidity file, to kaleido-go here in case it's helpful:
https://github.com/kaleido-io/kaleido-go

> Another possibility for others encountering "out of gas" calling across contracts - In Geth if a `require` call fails in a called contract, the error is reported as "out of gas" (rather than "execution reverted", or a detailed reason for the `require` failing).

Comment: I have modified the contract to include gas price as you suggested but still it is not working. I still get: status 0x0 Transaction mined but execution failed

Comment: This issue is now fixed in Kaleido. @MertOzdag - you should not run into the issue after you create a new environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to discard the return statement of `setValue` method in contract `TestA`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract TestA {
    uint public someValue;

    function setValue(uint a) public {
        someValue = a;
    }
}
```